Hide row based on cell value (date): type mismatch
I am monitoring maintenance progress, and would like to hide rows where the cell value (date) is >= 45 days ago.
When setting the date on column S, I get:

Run-time error 13: Type mismatch.

Even when changing the format to US date mmddyyyy instead of ddmmyyyy.
The code only works till row S18.
Sub Hidedatemorethan45days()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("S6:S67")
        If cell.Value - Date >= 45 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

The column S has a formula referred from different sheet as below:

=IF($C$3="QC67",'Master records List'!BL6,IF($C$3="QC66",'Master records List'!BJ6,IF($C$3="QC65",'Master records List'!BH6,IF($C$3="QC64",'Master records List'!BF6,IF($C$3="QC63",'Master records List'!BD6,IF($C$3="QC62",'Master records List'!BB6,IF($C$3="QC61",'Master records List'!AZ6,"請輸入機號")))))))  



If your code only work until S18, that probably means that whatever is in the row that isn't working, is neither a date nor is it a number. I would wager a guess that it's probably a string, formatted in such a way it appears in line with the rest of the dates.

I can't follow the links to those images so your description of your problem is incomplete. Post the data in your question.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Technical%20reasons,byte%20and%20every%20millisecond%20count.

If your cells contain strings (that may look like a date, but they are not), setting the date format doesn't change that. Setting number or data format changes only the way data is displayed.

Find the cells which are not working
Sub Hidedatemorethan45days()
    Dim cell As Range, check As Boolean
    For Each cell In Range("S6:S67")
    check = False
    If IsNumeric(cell.Value2) Then
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
         check = True
             If cell.Value2 - Date >= 45 Then
              cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
             Else
              cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
             End If
        End If
    End If
  If Not check Then Debug.Print cell.Address ' show cells which are not date in the debug window
    Next cell
End Sub

